# uploading multiple file to server

Tags: java

Uploading multiple files to the server. Here is the code for client machine:

```
void SendFile() throws Exception
{        

    String path;
    System.out.print("Enter File Path :");
    path=br.readLine();

    File f=new File(path);
    File files[]=f.listFiles();
    String fileName;

      for(File file:files)
      {
         if(file.isFile())

         {

             fileName=file.getName();
             dout.writeUTF(fileName);


    System.out.println("Sending File ..."+fileName);
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
    int ch;
    do
    {
        ch=fin.read();
        dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
    }
    while(ch!=-1);
    fin.close();
    System.out.println(din.readUTF());

    }  

 }
}
```

but after sending single file the program yields error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/bdi-user/Desktop/files (Is a directory)
```

Comment: unix is case sensitive.. could you please check the folder name... whether it is `files` or `Files`

Answer (score 2):

Don't read from the directory `f` but from the file you called `file`.

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file);
```